# How to create a boss bar that counts up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So, I'm creating a server on minecraft with a minigame. I have most of the stuff set up, I just need to know how to make a boss bar that counts up. So, I have my boss bar name as gen1, and I learned that the best way to do this is with scoreboards. I have a repeater clock set up that will run through the command blocks needed to increase my Timer score named gen1Timer, which increases by 2 with every pulse. The other command blocks are supposed to run the commands to add 10 to the boss bar every time. So once the gen1Timer value hits ten, it adds ten to the boss bar, and then eventually resets. How do I go about doing this? If you could, be detailed, thank you!

Comment: What are the commands you used so far? And what exactly is your question? How to set the value of boss bars?

Comment: @FabianRöling Well, I used commands to set up my boss bar, and all the color, and style, etc. My question is how do I effectively add to the boss bar value. I know you can set the value of the value of the boss bar. But I want to know how I can add to it. I have a clock circuit, and I want it to power a command block(s) that add a certain number to the boss bar. I currently have the Timer set up, so every time the timer amount reaches 10, its supposed to add 10 value to the boss bar, and then reset the timer. I just need to know the best way to add a specific number to a boss bar, not set it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply values dynamically to bossbars using `/execute store`. For example, to get the value of a player called `hugo` in a scoreboard called `foo` into a bossbar with the ID `bar`, you can use this command:

```
/execute store result bossbar bar value run scoreboard players get hugo foo
```

You can also set `max` instead of `value` for the bossbar. Scaling is not an option here, you have to modify the scoreboard for this, for example by using `/scoreboard players operation`.